# How to pass user input (string) that is already saved as a variable as a parameter?

Tags: python, string, variables, parameters

```py
import random
import time
from sports import sports
from states import states

def get_word():
    while True:
        user_input = input('Select a category (sports or states): ')
        if user_input in ['sports', 'states']:
            return random.choice([user_input])
        else:
            print(f'{user_input} is not a valid category, try again!')
            print('\n')
```

This function get_word() is trying to pick a random word from a list depending on the category that a user picks. I am having a problem with line 10 because the variable user_input is a string either 'sports' or 'states'. These strings are already variable names for a list imported from other python scripts. When I call random.choice(user_input) I get a random letter from the string 'sports' or 'states' depending on what the user picked. Instead, I want a random item from either the variable sports or states. How do I change the variable, user_input, which is saved as a string, to call the actual variables.

Comment: please dont paste your code as a screenshot.

Comment: how should I post my code then ?

Comment: copy your code add it as a text

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Ok thank you, but do you know a solution to my question, please?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: If you want an answer to your problem, please follow the posting guidelines.  It is not appropriate to ask for an answer when you haven't finished asking the question.

Comment: I have fixed it... I think. Please let me know if this is better.

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of variables, thinkin terms of *objects*. Your input is a string. Create a map from *strings to whatever objects `sporst` and `states`* are, (presumably, lists?). By map, I mean, use a `dict`

Comment: you should use `random.choice(['sports', 'states'])` instead of `random.choice([user_input])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only a few possibilities, it's often easier to make a set of `if` statements:

```
if user_input in ['sports', 'states']:
    if user_input == 'sports':
        return random.choice(sports)
    elif user_input == 'states':
        return random.choice(states)
```

If you instead want to be able to handle an arbitrarily large number of categories, then you can use a `dict` to organize them, and then pick which one to use out of the `dict` whenever you need to:

```
user_input_options = {
    'sports': sports,
    'states': states,
}

...

if user_input in user_input_options:  # this checks the keys of user_input_options, which makes it identical to ['sports', 'states'] for our purposes
    return random.choice(user_input_options[user_input])
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! And yes I am eventually going to add more categories so I wanted to avoid if statements.